# Getting error: 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.' for logout route in Django/React app

Tags: reactjs, django, cors, auth0, django-cors-headers

I have an app using React/Django, with Auth0 for authentication. I've followed [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-fix-django-cors-error) to fix any CORS errors, and all my routes are not running into any issues, except for my logout route.

I'm creating a logout button, which will flush the user's session on Django and redirect to the Auth0 logout page as well.

### urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
   ...
   path('logout/, views.logout, name = 'logout')
]
```

### views.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth import logout as django_logout
def logout(request):
   django_logout(request)
   domain = settings.AUTH0_DOMAIN
   client_id = settings.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID
   return_to = '127.0.0.1:8000'
   return redirect(f'https://{domain}/v2/logout?client_id={client_id}&returnTo={returnTo}')
```

### App.jsx

```js
const App = () => {
   ...
   const logout = async () => {
      await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/logout/')
   }
   
   return (
      <div>
         ...
         <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
      <div>
   )
}
```

When the user logs out, I'm getting a CORS error despite importing and configuring `django-cors-headers` and not getting this error for any other route. Specifically, the error is `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Answer (score 0):

the resource you referred to used these values in settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
# or
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['http://localhost:5000']
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ('http://localhost:5000')
```

try using these values instead (and specifying them correctly!)

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [...]
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES = ...
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = False
```